# Use defined column names in conditional formatting formulars

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a table with 28 columns. 8 columns are calculated values. The other 20 columns are user-input.

Now I want to setup conditional formatting to highlight rows which do not have values in all of the required cells. Not all cells are required.

Format is just a background-color change.

Named columns are necessary if you want to move the whole row when you sort by a column in a table - otherwise things get messed up.

So lets say my required columns are *Foo*, *Bar* and *Baz* . I setup a conditional formatting with this formular:

```
=OR(
    ISBLANK(Foo);
    ISBLANK(Bar);
    ISBLANK(Baz);
)
```

Foo, Bar and Baz are ranges over single columns, like $A$2:$A$52

But I actually use 10 instead of 3 columns. Range for the conditional formatting is `=$A$2:$AF$42`.

When I apply the formatting excel basically just goes into *not responding* forever.

When I just use a single column, without `OR` like `ISBLANK(Foo)` it's working just fine. As soon as I bring in the `OR` things get messed up.

I also tried setting the *Stop If True* flag which didn't fix things.

I also tried to move the formular to a custom column - but that's the same issue as soon as I try to acces it per named column.

Any idea how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: What are the ranges you are  checking? (i.e. what ranges are Foo, Bar, Baz and so on?) If they are contiguous a simple COUNTA would do the job

Comment: Could you please post some sample data and the Range value of Named Ranges or are entire Column !!

Answer (score 0):

> =OR(
>       ISBLANK(Foo);
>       ISBLANK(Bar);
>       ISBLANK(Baz);
>   )

The formula that you're using is an array formula. Conditional formatting doesn't work well with array formula's.

I suggest you use this formula in any specific cell (say "B1"). Then in the conditional formatting, you can refer this cell like so **= $B$1**.This should give you the desired result

**Note:** in cell B!, after entering the formula, make sure to hit "**CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER**" for the formula to work properly as this is an array formula.

**Array Formula resources:**

1. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d
2. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7